# How to connect React frontend to Flask backend URL in production?

Tags: reactjs, flask, heroku, url, fetch

I am hosting a Flask backend which is deployed at e.g. backend.herokuapp.com/test. I am now trying to have my deployed React frontend (e.g. frontend.herokuapp.com) to connect to this backend:

```
useEffect(() => {
 fetch("/test", {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
  },
}).then((response) =>
  response.json().then((data) => {
    setTest(data.tests);
  })
);}, []);
```

For development I used a proxy in `package.json`:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

But now in production I want to access my backend without localhost. How can I do this? Do I still need a proxy? Because my frontend now automatically uses the Request URL: **frontend.herokuapp.com/test** instead of **backend.herokuapp.com/test**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell your frontend where to find the endpoint you are trying to fetch, like (in a dirty variant):

```
useEffect(() => {
 fetch("https://backend.herokuapp.com/test", {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
  },
}).then((response) =>
  response.json().then((data) => {
    setTest(data.tests);
  })
);}, []);
```

Ideally you would use environment variables for your dev and your prod environment (in a separate `.env` file). So instead of writing the absolute path in your fetch function, your would end up declaring a `const API_URL=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}` and then use it in your fetch function.

```
fetch(`${API_URL}/test`, {
```

Thus, you need to ensure that your environment is picking up the right env variable. More about [how to use environment variables in CRA apps](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables).

Comment: I have tried this earlier but the problem is that this solution leads to the following error: '...has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.' Would there be any alternative solutions?

Comment: You are taking the right path. Please checkout what the CORS header issue means. You need to setup your BE to allow requests from your (fe) domain, this might help you: [Flask-Cors](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)